# Retreat from deleted directory

Tags: command-line

Suppose I am editing some files. I have (say) a terminal open and a gui file manager.
I am currently in `/my/very/long/and/winding/directory/path` in the terminal.
In my gui, I delete 
`/my/very/long/and/winding/directory`
Back in the terminal, I try `cd ..` and I get an error, since the directory no longer exists.
No big deal. I could type `cd /my/very/long/and/winding` to get back where I want to go. But if I'm too lazy to type that, is there a nice way to go back to the nearest directory that still exists?

edit: `cd ../../` is one solution, in this particular case. But I'm wondering if there is a more general answer, where I don't know how many steps back I need to take.

Comment: Slightly related: [Remove a directory from inside using the command line interface](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219496/80216).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `PWD` is correct, one can back out in ZShell thusly.

```
% cd ~/tmp
% mkdir -p a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
% cd !$
cd a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
% rm -rf ~/tmp/a
% undir
% pwd
/Users/jmates/tmp
%
```

The custom `undir` function does the walk-back-out-the-path-chain loop:

```
function undir {
  local dir
  dir=$PWD:h

  while [[ $dir != / ]]; do
    builtin cd -q $dir 2>/dev/null
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
      dir=/
    else
      dir=$dir:h
    fi
  done
}
```

Note that you cannot rely on the `pwd` command, as that gives different results than the shell-maintained `PWD` variable:

```
% mkdir -p a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
% cd !$
cd a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
% rm -rf ~/tmp/a
% pwd
/Users/jmates/tmp/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
% cd ..
% pwd
.
% echo $PWD
/Users/jmates/tmp/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
%
```

Shells that are not `zsh` will undoubtably require other solutions.

Comment: I hoped there might be a 'vanilla' bash solution, without using any custom functions.  If not, I guess this is the next best thing!

Comment: @SauceCode - maybe like this for bash: `p=$(dirname "$PWD"); while [[ ! -d "$p" ]]; do p=$(dirname "$p"); done; cd "$p"`

Comment: @don_crissti Nice. With an alias that would be quite straightforward to use.

Comment: Note that in `zsh` you can do `array[-1]=()` to _pop_ an element off the end on an array. See also $dir:h to get the dirname (head) of a path.

Answer (score 6):

To go back by one level of directory based on the directory path rather than the `..` link:

```
cd $PWD:h
```

Or the portable method:

```
cd "${PWD%/*}"
```

(quotes optional in zsh; quotes optional in other shells if the directory name doesn't contain whitespace or `\[*?`)

Repeat the `:h` or `/*` as many times as desired to go further up in the directory hierarchy.

Alternatively, type `cd $PWD` then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to expand `$PWD` to its value and manually edit the result. (Depending on your completion and line editor settings, you may need to add a `/` after `$PWD` before pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, to press the key that you've bound to `expand-or-complete` (default <kbd>Tab</kbd>) or `expand-or-complete-prefix` or `expand-word` (default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>).)

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the directory you are in, cd .. will not work as the current directory exists without name and without connection to the rest of the world. So .. does no longer exist.

Every bourne shell alike should allow to write a function that creates a copy of $PWD and traverses the path as far as it still exists.

Comment: Posix shells and zsh fail as well. With regards to the bourne shell, you are mistaken. You may be right for a bourne shell before 1989. Modern shells including bourne track paths for symbolic links but this does not help here.

Comment: You seem to missinterpret things. All modern shells just check where they are after chdir. All shells call chdir(".."). Ksh and zsh call chdir("$PWD/..") in addition but this of course fails as well.

Comment: What I reported has been tested with bash, ksh and zsh. I tested the default behavior on Solaris. If you see different behavior, there must be constraint that causes the deviating behavior you observed.

Comment: OK, that's part misunderstanding/talking about different things and Linux vs Solaris. After more checking, there's also some differences for bash between sh mode and non-sh mode. The behaviour of ksh88 and ksh93 also differs. Most of what you said and what I've said is true in some contexts and inaccurate in others. A long article would be needed here to summarize the different behaviours. See also [Symbolic link recursion - what makes it “reset”?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79621) for some more info. I'll delete my comments for now.

Comment: OK, I checked ksh again and found that I was too quick and oversight somethiing; ksh does a stat on $PWD/. and this of course fails as well. So I cannot see a real different behavior. The funny notice for ksh is that if you recreate a directory of the same name of the removed directory, it "works" even though the state dis not change. My impression is that ksh does not follow the rules from the POSIX cd documentation. The way I understand the POSIX standard, even cd ../.. with two directories missing should result in a "successful" chdir to what the user expects.

Comment: As the POSIX standard requires to do string operations on $PWD first, before doing the actual chdir(), I am now planning to change the Bourne Shell to follow this text as it seems to be a real improvement. Given the fact that neither bash, nor ksh, nor zsh currently deal with a removed directory that is skipped by a chdir .., it seems that no shell currently follows the POSIX standard and the Bourne Shell might become the first correct one...Note that this makes sense when $PWD always holds the normalized real path and when the user likes a physical chdir ".." based on this $PWD.

Comment: See the link I gave. Some shells check that $PWD still correspond to the current directory before doing a cd (and recompute $PWD). Some don't (dash and ksh93u+ on Linux at least will do a chdir(dirname($PWD)) even if the current directory has been removed or moved elsewhere). Also note that on Linux, `chdir("..")` works in a deleted directory (even `../..` when both directories were deleted as the kernel keeps track of that somehow).

Comment: OpenSolaris added pwd() as a syscall to allow Linux userspace emulation. Solaris still behaves as expected for removed files: there is no name anymore.

Comment: My main concern with that logical handling of `..` (as already expressed at that linked answer) is that it's only applied to the shell's `cd` and `pwd`, not to other commands, which is possible cause of confusion. IMO, it's a ksh/POSIX misfeature. tcsh has a `set symlinks = expand` option to _expand_ those `..` in any unquoted argument to any command, but I don't like that idea either. Can cause bad surprises as in `ssh host rm ../foo`.

Comment: I'll have a look at your other thread, but this may take some time as your text is very long.